# Permissions for serialport communication for a program

Tags: permissions, java, serial-port

**Introduction:**

I'm building a Java software that performs serial communications by using jSerialComm library.
I've noticed that if I run the .jar with sudo, it will act properly, but not otherwise, so it is a permissions problem. I need to generate an installer for this .jar, and maybe we can do something around there to solve this before the program starts.

**Question:**

How can I make it work without using sudo, but also in such way that I can integrate the procedure to an installer?

**Additional information:**

The ideal way should be:

1. The user downloads the program.
2. The user installs the program like any other (i.e. './configure').
3. The program is now allowed to communicate over serial port.
4. The program can now run.

Comment: Does it work without `sudo` if you add the invoking user to the `dialout` group?

Comment: Good question. No, it doesn't. The actual user is already a member of 'dialout'. It should work, right?

Comment: What are the ownerships/permissions of the serial device in /dev?

Comment: The question has already been answered with the details of what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @steeldriver and @user535733 correctly wondered, effectively, the permission needed was 'dialout'. So by using the command `sudo adduser *user* dialout`, it should start working.

I must add there was something else happening that didn't allow it to work properly. This was overpassed by typing `sudo apt remove modemmanager` and adding the using the user again to the dialout group.

Thanks very much to those who helped finding the answer.